# Finding and counting repeated occurrences

Tags: r

I wish to make a function, which will accept three arguments (starting position, ending position, length), and by that function, I wish to find out, how many times each of the different pattern of that particular length appear and then I wish to extract the maximum one. Sounds confusing.

Comment: it's an interesting question - you're just missing the bit where you mention how you've tried to already work this out in R and where exactly you need help.

Comment: Your first example should be `"aaabaaacaaac"` I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    countSubstring<-function(string,start,end,len) {
      startChar<-seq(start,end,by=len)
      table(substring(string,startChar,startChar+(len-1)))
    }

    string<-"aabaaaabaaaacaaaabaaaabaa"

    countSubstring(string,start=1,end=15,len=5)

     aabaa aacaa 
       2     1
```

Comment: How can I return just the substring having the maximum count?

Comment: Great. Thanks. Also, I have one more doubt in a code that I have made. Is there a possibility you can have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: for the help. Can you help me in just a small query?